# Remove just the text within square brackets from a string with regex + gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

```
text = "This [is] a [fill]-in-the-[blank]"
```

I'm looking for the regular expression to do some magic for me:

```
new_text = text.gsub(/[magic happens]/, "")

=> "This [] a []-in-the-[]"
```

My code is Ruby, but I'll bet that doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = "This [is] a [fill]-in-the-[blank]"

text.gsub(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/, "")
```

or

```
text.gsub(/(?<=\[)[^\]]+?(?=\])/, "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this would work:

```
text = "This [is] a [fill]-in-the-[blank]"
text.gsub(/\[.+?\]/, '[]')
#=> "This [] a []-in-the-[]"
```

Comment: Haha..  That's a great answer.  I'm definitely going to upvote it, but I feel like I ought to wait a bit to see if I get a "right" answer.  If I don't, I'll change the question and give you the green checkmark.

Comment: See Sawa's answer for a way to do it using your template.  I think using the simpler regex makes it a lot easier to read, though!

Comment: I agree.  I'm going to use your answer, but I'll accept his.  Looks like you're going to win the up-vote battle.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I used [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to prototype this, given your test case -> http://rubular.com/r/TgdjOtc4Ru From here, you can remove the matches or something similar:

```
[5] pry(main)> text = "This [is] a [fill]-in-the[blank]"
=> "This [is] a [fill]-in-the[blank]"
[6] pry(main)> text.gsub(/\[(\w+)\]/) { |match| "[]" }
=> "This [] a []-in-the[]"
```

There is probably a prettier way to do that :-)

Comment: That works, Ron.  But I want whitespace within the brackets to match too.  That wasn't in my example, but it's true.

Comment: Gotcha - I'd highly recommend using the tool I linked for prototyping regular expressions in the future. While you can just use a ruby REPL (like pry or irb), these regex specific tools have some additional niceties that usually help me figure out what I'm trying to do more quickly

Comment: Thanks, Ron.  I did use Rubular actually.  And I figured out how to match exactly what I needed to.  For some reason, though I got stuck on the idea of leaving the []s behind by using look aheads and look behinds (instead of the much more readable way you and chron did it), and I didn't know how to do them until Sawa illustrated it.

Comment: I've just needed the same solution as you (a thousand years later haha), @vlasits! Just to document it: https://rubular.com/r/narcp8Nvzwd8dz

Comment: Nice!  Glad to hear my old problems helped someone get a new solution.